# How do I check the value of 'binlog_do_db' in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to debug why my DML statements aren't ending up in the binlogs. The master and slave appear to be talking to eachother and the slave status indicates that it caught up properly to the most recent log file.

I did a `show variables LIKE '%binlog%';` with this output, but `binlog_do_db` is not there.

```
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name                           | Value                |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| binlog_cache_size                       | 32768                |
| binlog_checksum                         | CRC32                |
| binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates | OFF                  |
| binlog_error_action                     | ABORT_SERVER         |
| binlog_format                           | ROW                  |
| binlog_group_commit_sync_delay          | 0                    |
| binlog_group_commit_sync_no_delay_count | 0                    |
| binlog_gtid_simple_recovery             | ON                   |
| binlog_max_flush_queue_time             | 0                    |
| binlog_order_commits                    | ON                   |
| binlog_row_image                        | FULL                 |
| binlog_rows_query_log_events            | OFF                  |
| binlog_stmt_cache_size                  | 32768                |
| innodb_api_enable_binlog                | OFF                  |
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog          | OFF                  |
| log_statements_unsafe_for_binlog        | ON                   |
| max_binlog_cache_size                   | 18446744073709547520 |
| max_binlog_size                         | 104857600            |
| max_binlog_stmt_cache_size              | 18446744073709547520 |
| sync_binlog                             | 1                    |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

After much effort and grief, I found that in the previous administrator must have been trying to get replication to work and put these lines into the `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` file

```
# Setup Incremental Backups
log-bin                 = /srv/ddisk/backups/mysql/mysql_inc
expire_logs_days        = 3
max_binlog_size         = 100M
server-id               = 1
binlog_do_db            = include_database_name
```

The last line is probably the culprit (though I will likely clean out that whole config block since I have them in the `my.cnf` config file already. In any case, I am now trying to verify that this configuration is actually being read by MySQL, but I'm unable to figure out what query to run to find this variable.

Would someone happen to know how to find `binlog_do_db`?

Thanks ahead of time

Answer (score 0):

You can check using mysql prompt on the master node below:

mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS;

It will show Binary log file, position, Binlog_Do_DB, Binlog_Ignore_DB parameter and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem but didn't find a satisfactory answer.

It is impossible to query the corresponding value when the replication is not enabled.

So I wrote a mysql [plugin](https://github.com/shapled/inspector) to export rpl_filter and binlog_filter.

how to use it:

1. install this plugin.
2. run `show status like 'inspector_binlog_filter_do_db';`

The result is this:

```
+-------------------------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name                             | Value  |
+-------------------------------------------+--------+
| inspector_binlog_filter_do_db             | test   |
+-------------------------------------------+--------+
```

Note: this plugin maybe is **NOT** thread-safe.

Comment: Please add an explicit disclaimer that the extension you’re suggesting is made by yourself. If not, you risk your answer being deleted for being spam.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).